# Limitations of Marketing Cloud Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, marketing-cloud-connect

I am designing a proposal for a client who has already run pilots, and hinted that they have faced certain limitations with marketing cloud connector (native salesforce integrator).

With the exception of sms tracking information not been sent back to sales cloud, and possible API limitations on the use of Data Stream, I can't seem to think of anymore. I would like to put my best foot forward and welcome any input or pointers on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be cautious with multi-org setup, since it has some limitations/shortcomings, which you can find [listed here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/features/multi_org_account_configuration/upgrading_to_multi_org/).

It is especially vital to note, that you cannot disable multi-org once it is enabled. I will personally go for the single-org integration, and if needed, pass data from parent BU using query activities.

Comment: Thanks for this. Multi org is required as they will be connecting to multiple SF instances. I am more concerned with any limitations of the connector.

Answer (score 2):

Another limitation is that the related list "individual email results" is not a lightning enabled object, so if you're using service console in lightning, you'll need to build a custom object that scrapes the IER related list.

Additionally, [here's](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200694/how-do-i-track-marketing-cloud-mobile-connectsms-data-in-salesforce) a link to an SMS history posting solution.

Answer (score 1):

Data streams work only at parent BU level but with multi-org this can be resolved

Also, Marketing Cloud Connect is only one way data flow (except for some tracking information)

Comment: Thanks for this. Since we have a multi org set up in mind, are there any other considerations for MC connect?