# How do I track Marketing cloud Mobile Connect(SMS) data in Salesforce?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, mobileconnect

How can I have my Marketing Cloud Mobile connect(SMS) data in Salesforce? I am aware of Individual Email Send's related list which consists of Email's tracking data back in Salesforce. I would like to have the same related list in for Mobile tracking data back in Salesforce using Marketing cloud connect.

Is there any standard functionality available or do I need to use API's to achieve this? (If API's is the only option please let me know if any documentation available for the same.)

Answer (score 4):

There is no out of the box solution for this as of yet, so you do need to do something custom in order to achieve it.

There are two smart ways to achieve this.

**1)** Use AMPscript to store messages directly to Salesforce.

Create a custom object in Salesforce and link it to your Account object, this is going to be holding your SMS history.

In SMS, add AMPscript to create a new record in Salesforce. This can be stored to SMS header/footer for an example. 
This method requires that one of your MobileConnect Demographic attributes holds Salesforce PersonContactID field value.

Basic example:

```
%%[
CreateSalesforceObject('SMS_tracking__c', 3, 'Phone’ ,MOBILE_NUMBER, 'MessageName', 'smsName', 'sentTime', now() )
]%%
```

**2)** Store the results to a Data Extension through AMPscript and configure Journey Builder to use this Data Extension to update/create new Salesforce records via SF event activities.

This method is slower, but gives you more flexibility.

However, note that you cannot ever know if the Contact actually opened the SMS, as this is tracked only by the carrier and is not provided back to Marketing Cloud. This means Marketing Cloud is only able to commit to show you either delivered/undelivered - which states if this SMS was delivered to the carrier or not.

AMPscript functions to look into:

[CreateSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm)

[UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm)